# Kafka manual commit based on conditions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka Sink Task which is listening to a Kafka topic where I want the message to get processed and persisted in DB first and then want to manually commit the offset just to ensure there are no loss of messages that have come to a topic but not persisted in DB.

To check if the message has been persisted, I am using a custom event with ApplicationEventPublisher in SpringBoot app which is publishing that custom event upon successful commit in DB.

I am having an @EventListener listening to that custom event which has to notify @KafkaListener that the message can be acknowledged now.

Also after fetching the records from Kafka, if the processing and persistence is successful then only I want to manually commit the offset else it should read from the same offset again.

Below is the set of things that I have configured:-

- enable.auto.commit = false
- AckMode has been set to MANUAL

> ```
> @KafkaListener(containerFactory = "kafkaProvider",
>         topics = "test")
> public void receive(@Payload V payload,
>                     @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
>                     @Header(value = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = false) K key,
>                     @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offsets,
>                     Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
>     
>   if(message is persisted){
>
>     // This is added for manually committing the message
>     acknowledgement.acknowledge();
>     
>     // Send the data to the provided topic with the provided key and no partition.
>     kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, value);
>    } 
> }
>
> @EventListener
> private boolean checkMessagePersisted(MessageAcknowledgeEvent event) {
>     if(event.isPersisted()){
>         return true;
>     }else{
>         logger.error();
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

Here there are 2 suggestions I need:-

1. If I use acknowledgement.acknowledge() to manually commit the message, do I still have to use kafkatemplate.send() method. If not, then how will it know which key and data are required to send to topic
2. Any best practices for sharing the flag value from @EventListener to @KafkaListener so that the message can be committed now only if the persistence flag check is true

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do; why not just persist before acknowledging and, if there is an exception, the offset won't be committed and, with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, the record will be redelivered. Sending the data to another topic with the template. If you are persisting to the db asynchronously, why? And, are you suspending the listener until you get the async event?

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, I have defined my custom KafkaProvider class which is being used as a utility with another repo to listen for messages from a particular topic. I cannot persist it before committing the offset since it is a more a general library being used. I have to process the message and convert it to a POJO and persist that and if there is any error persisting it, rollback is happening. But if the db commit is success, then have to communicate that persisted status to my utility which will actually manually commit the offset.

Comment: But in your code, the `acknowledgement` is done in the listener itself - it's really not clear what you are doing, you need to show more code and/or pseudo code. Committing offsets asynchronously is dangerous, you might commit them in the wrong order.

Comment: @GaryRussell, I dont want to acknowledge in listener but instead when custom event is listened as mentioned in EventListener. Currently the whole idea is to process and persist all the records in a single poll and then manually committing their offset and when the next poll is done, their offset commit is done in such a way that it should be next to last commit in previous poll. Just ignore the acknowledgement and kafkatemplate.send method call. Those calls have to done after custom event flag is checked

Comment: @GaryRussell, updated the receive method

Comment: It still makes no sense; with this code, you are acknowledging the new message, not thee one that you persisted. You need to somehow save off the ack for the persisted message and ack that one, not the new one. And, as I said, you need to be careful to ack them in the right order. And, what happens when there are no more messages? The last persisted one will never be acked. You can save the ack someplace and ack it on your event thread instead, the ack will queued for the consumer thread and processed before the next poll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218843/discussion-between-mangla-and-gary-russell).